# Android Audio Player

Tags: android

I have and audio recorder and player first i can record audio then the recorded audio can be played ,when audio is playing i want my seekbar thumb move smoothly but currently it have no smooth movement also the fast switching of play and pause sometimes fail my application by saying that illegal state :anybody please suggest a solution for improving my audio player . recding no pblm

```
public class RecorderActivity extends Activity{
    public static int          AUDIO_RECORDING_RESULT=0;
 public static int       FROM_AUDIO_RECDING_HOME=0;
 public static int       FROM_AUDIO_RECDING_SEARCH=0;
 public static int       FROM_AUDIO_RECDING=0;

 private static MediaRecorder                 recorder;
    private static Button                        recd_stop_audio;
    private static Button                        audio_play_pause;
    private static Chronometer                   audio_recding_time;
    private static Chronometer                   audio_playtime_begin;
    private static TextView                      audio_playtime_end;
    public static  int                           audio_play_pause_flag         = 1;
    private static int                           audio_recding_stop_flag       = 1;
    private static SeekBar                       audio_seekbar_play_indication;
    private static View                          v1;
    private static View        v2;
    private static View        v3;
    private static TextView       textview_audio_information_grade;
    private static TextView                      textview_audio_information1;
    private static TextView                      textview_audio_information2_1;
    private static TextView                      textview_audio_information2_2;
    private static TextView                      textview_audio_information2;
    private static TextView                      textview_audio_information3; 
    private static int                           audio_seekbar_progress;
    private static int                           audio_seekbar_incr;
    private Button                               continue_audio;
    private static Button                        delete_recding;
    private static MediaPlayer                   mp;
    private static int                           audio_paused_flag             = 0;
    private static TextView                      txt_audio_serviceprovidername;


 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.audio);
  MyCustomesData.context=RecorderActivity.this;
   final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(RecorderActivity.this);
   audio_paused_flag=0;
   FROM_AUDIO_RECDING=0;
   AUDIO_RECORDING_RESULT=0;

   MyCustomesData.sumitAReport_PAGE=MyCustomesConstants.USER_AUDIO;
   continue_audio = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button_Voice_Record_Continue);
   textview_audio_information_grade=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.Description_grade);
         textview_audio_information1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Description);
         textview_audio_information2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Description2);
         textview_audio_information2_1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.Description2_1);
         textview_audio_information2_2=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.Description2_2);
         textview_audio_information3= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.Description3);
         v1 = (View) findViewById(R.id.View1);
         v2 = (View) findViewById(R.id.View22);
         v3=  (View) findViewById(R.id.View33);
         audio_seekbar_play_indication = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.SeekBar01);
         audio_playtime_begin = (Chronometer) findViewById(R.id.TimerStart);
         audio_playtime_end = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TimerStop);
         audio_recding_time = (Chronometer) findViewById(R.id.Rec_Timer_ID);
         recorder = new MediaRecorder();
         recd_stop_audio = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button_record_sound);
         audio_play_pause = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button_Play_Sound);
         delete_recding = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button_Delete_Sound);
         txt_audio_serviceprovidername=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.TextView_Audio_Provider);
         txt_audio_serviceprovidername.setText(MyCustomesData.MyCustomesListContext.getProviderName());
         audio_seekbar_play_indication.setOnClickListener(null);
         audio_seekbar_play_indication.setEnabled(false);
         audio_play_pause.setEnabled(false);
            delete_recding.setEnabled(false);
         showHelpInformation();

         if(MyCustomesData.MyCustomesListContext.isAudioRecd())
         {
          showRecdingInformation();
          audio_play_pause.setEnabled(true);
             delete_recding.setEnabled(true);
         }

           recd_stop_audio.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

               public void onClick(View v) {
                  if (audio_recding_stop_flag == 0) {

                    audiorecding();

                   } else {

                    audiorecding();

                   }

               }
           });

           audio_play_pause.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

               public void onClick(View v) {
                playaudio();
                             }
           });
           audio_recding_time.setOnChronometerTickListener(new OnChronometerTickListener() {

    public void onChronometerTick(Chronometer chronometer) {
     if(chronometer.getText().equals("02:00"))
     {
      audiorecding();
     }

    }
   });
         **//UPDATING SEEKBAR USING CHRONOMETER**  
           audio_playtime_begin.setOnChronometerTickListener(new OnChronometerTickListener() {

               public void onChronometerTick(Chronometer chronometer) {

               if(!audio_playtime_begin.getText().equals("00:00"))
                {
                 audio_seekbar_play_indication.setProgress(audio_seekbar_progress);
                    audio_seekbar_progress = audio_seekbar_progress + audio_seekbar_incr;

                }
                else
                 audio_seekbar_progress=1;


               }
           });



           delete_recding.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

               public void onClick(View v) {

                   audio_seekbar_progress = 1;
                           if (mp != null) {
                           if (audio_play_pause_flag == 0) {
                          audio_play_pause_flag =1;
                          audio_playtime_begin.stop();
                          mp.stop();
                             mp.reset();
                             mp.release();
                             audio_play_pause.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.play1);

                           }
                       }

                       recorder = new MediaRecorder();
                       v1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                       v2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                       recd_stop_audio.setEnabled(true);
                       audio_play_pause.setEnabled(false);
                       delete_recding.setEnabled(false);
                          audio_play_pause.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.play1);
                       audio_play_pause_flag = 1;
                     audio_playtime_begin.stop();
                     audio_playtime_begin.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
                     audio_paused_flag = 0;
                       audio_playtime_end.setText("00:00"); // Seekbar End Time
                       audio_recding_time.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()); // Recording time
                       audio_seekbar_play_indication.setProgress(0);
                       MyCustomesData.MyCustomesListContext.setAudioRecd(false);
                       showHelpInformation();


               }
           });

           continue_audio.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

               public void onClick(View v) {
                System.out.println("The Staus of report"+MyCustomesData.MyCustomesListContext.isAudioRecd()+":"+MyCustomesData.MyCustomesListContext.getTextReport());

                if (audio_recding_stop_flag == 0)
                {
                 audiorecding();
                }
                if(audio_play_pause_flag == 0)
                {
                mp.stop();
                   mp.reset();
                   mp.release();
                   audio_seekbar_play_indication.setProgress(100); //Max value
                     audio_playtime_begin.stop();
                      audio_play_pause_flag = 1;
                     audio_play_pause.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.play1);
                }
              StringBuffer txtReport=new StringBuffer(MyCustomesData.MyCustomesListContext.getTextReport());
              String txtreport=new String(txtReport);
              txtreport=txtreport.trim();
             if(!MyCustomesData.MyCustomesListContext.isAudioRecd()&&txtreport.length()==0)
             {

               builder.setMessage("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.").setCancelable(false).setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                         public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                             dialog.cancel();
                             FROM_AUDIO_RECDING=0;
                       AUDIO_RECORDING_RESULT=0;
                       finish();
                         }
                     });

                     AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
                     alert.setTitle("Attention");
                     alert.setIcon(R.drawable.alert_dialog_icon);
                     alert.show();
             }

             else
              {
              AUDIO_RECORDING_RESULT=1;
              finish();

              }

               }

           });


 }
    static void audiorecding()
    {

          audio_play_pause.setEnabled(false);
          delete_recding.setEnabled(false);

        if (audio_recding_stop_flag == 0) {




           int maxtime = audio_seekbar_play_indication.getMax();
         audio_recding_stop_flag = 1;
         audio_recding_time.stop();
          recorder.stop();
            recorder.reset();
            recorder.release(); 
            audio_seekbar_progress = 1;
            recd_stop_audio.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.rec_btn);
          audio_play_pause.setEnabled(true);
            delete_recding.setEnabled(true);

           MyCustomesData.MyCustomesListContext.setAudioRecd(true);
           if(audio_recding_time.getText().equals("00:00"))
           {
            audio_recding_time.setText("00:01");
            MyCustomesData.MyCustomesListContext.setAudioRecdingTime( "00:01");  
           }
           else

           MyCustomesData.MyCustomesListContext.setAudioRecdingTime( audio_recding_time.getText().toString());

           showRecdingInformation();

        } 
        else {


            audio_recding_stop_flag = 0;


            try {
             showHelpInformation();
             audio_playtime_begin.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
               audio_playtime_end.setText("00:00");
               audio_seekbar_play_indication.setProgress(0);
             MyCustomesListMain.path = InitialValueLoader.sanitizePath("MyCustomAudio/VoiceReport");
                InitialValueLoader.filecheck(MyCustomesListMain.path);
                audio_play_pause.setEnabled(false);
                delete_recding.setEnabled(false);
                recd_stop_audio.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.recording_stop);
                audio_recding_time.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());

                recorder.release();
                audio_recding_time.start();  
                recorder = new MediaRecorder();
                recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC); // AudioSource
                recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.DEFAULT); // OutputFormat
                recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.DEFAULT);
                recorder.setOutputFile(MyCustomesListMain.path);
                recorder.prepare();
                recorder.start();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                recorder.reset();
                recorder.release();
            } 

    }
    }
    private static void playaudio()
     {


           showRecdingInformation();

           recd_stop_audio.setEnabled(false);
              if (audio_play_pause_flag == 1) {
               audio_play_pause_flag = 0;
               v2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
               audio_playtime_end.setText(audio_recding_time.getText());
               audio_play_pause.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.play2);

                     if (audio_paused_flag == 1) {
                         audio_paused_flag = 0;

                         int stoppedMilliseconds = 0;

                         String chronoText = audio_playtime_begin.getText().toString();
                         String array[] = chronoText.split(":");
                         if (array.length == 2) {
                           stoppedMilliseconds = Integer.parseInt(array[0]) * 60 * 1000
                               + Integer.parseInt(array[1]) * 1000;
                         } else if (array.length == 3) {
                           stoppedMilliseconds = Integer.parseInt(array[0]) * 60 * 60 * 1000 
                               + Integer.parseInt(array[1]) * 60 * 1000
                               + Integer.parseInt(array[2]) * 1000;
                         }
                         stoppedMilliseconds=stoppedMilliseconds+1000;
                         audio_playtime_begin.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - stoppedMilliseconds);
                         audio_seekbar_progress=audio_seekbar_progress - 1;
                         audio_playtime_begin.start();
                         mp.start();


                     } else

                     {
                         v2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                         try {

                          audio_play_pause.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.play2);
                             audio_seekbar_progress = 1;
                                                  audio_seekbar_play_indication.setMax(getTotalAudioRecdingTime(MyCustomesData.MyCustomesListContext.getAudioRecdingTime()));
                             audio_play_pause.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.play2);
                             audio_playtime_end.setText(MyCustomesData.MyCustomesListContext.getAudioRecdingTime());
                             audio_seekbar_incr = 1;
                             audio_playtime_begin.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
                             audio_seekbar_play_indication.setProgress(0);
                             audio_playtime_begin.start();
                             mp = new MediaPlayer();
                             mp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

             public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
               mp.stop();
                           mp.reset();
                           mp.release();

                           audio_playtime_begin.stop();
                           audio_seekbar_play_indication.setProgress(0);
                           audio_playtime_begin.setText(MyCustomesData.MyCustomesListContext.getAudioRecdingTime());
                           audio_seekbar_play_indication.setProgress(getTotalAudioRecdingTime(MyCustomesData.MyCustomesListContext.getAudioRecdingTime())); //Max value
                             audio_play_pause_flag = 1;
                              audio_play_pause.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.play1);
                             recd_stop_audio.setEnabled(true);
             }
            });


                             mp.setDataSource(MyCustomesListMain.path);
                             mp.prepare();
                             mp.start();

                         } catch (Exception e) {

                             e.printStackTrace();
                             mp.stop();
                          mp.reset();
                          mp.release();
                             audio_playtime_begin.stop();



                         }

                     }

           }

           else

           {
            System.out.println("Audio Palyer Paused>>>>>>>>");
               audio_play_pause_flag = 1;
               audio_paused_flag = 1;
               audio_play_pause.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.play1);
               audio_playtime_begin.stop();

               mp.pause();

           }

     }
    private static int getTotalAudioRecdingTime(String recdingtime)
    {
    int timeM=Integer.valueOf(recdingtime.substring(0, 2)); 
    System.out.println("The Minute"+timeM);
    int timeS=Integer.valueOf(recdingtime.substring(3, 5));
    int totaltimeinS=timeM*60+timeS;
    return totaltimeinS;
    }

    private static void showHelpInformation()
    {


    }

    private static void showRecdingInformation()
    {



    }


}
```

Comment: 2 wishes: 1. improve your question, its hardly understandable (try to use dot and comma) and 2. please reduce the pasted code to the part where you try to update your seekbar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is quiet difficult to understand...
Advice you to follow WarrenFaith's suggestion :)

Anyway, based on your question, i have understood the following.

1. The seekbar is not smooth.
2. Using the UI widgets of your audio-player quickly leads to crashes.

For 1. increment the Progressbar by 0.5 rather than 1. This will smoothen the progress bar.

For 2. I think you need put the crash dump here... so that we can try to figure out what's the actual root cause... But don't dump entire logcat.

Cheers!!!

Comment: in seekbar i found only one method for setting progress ie setprogress and it take only integer values ,then how can i set the float values,also i set the increment of seekabr in my chronometer i think it execute with delay of 1s .

Comment: Sudeep, to make the progress bar smooth, what I would suggest you is set the Max size of progress bar to a very high range... like if u set the progress bar to increment between 1 .. 100 range, then rather than using 100 as max use 1000 in place.. This will smoothen the effect.By incrementing the progress bar by ... This is just a suggestion.. Cheers!